# Pass data from one ViewModel to another in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel `VM_App` with a list of names, with another View `V_NamesList` inside `V_App` that is supposed to display these names. For that, I am passing the list from `VM_App` to `VM_NamesList`, but the View gets redrawn while editing the names.

VM_App

```
class VM_App: ObservableObject {
    @Published var names: [String] = [
        "Tobias",
        "Jonathan",
        ""
    ]
}
```

V_App

```
struct V_App: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM_App = VM_App()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            V_NamesList(
                VM_NamesList(names: $vm.names)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

VM_NamesList

```
class VM_NamesList: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var names: [String]
    
    init(names: Binding<[String]>) {
        self._names = names
    }
}
```

V_NamesList

```
struct V_NamesList: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM_NamesList
    
    init(_ vm: VM_NamesList) {
        self.vm = vm
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(vm.names.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, name) in
            TextField("New Player", text: $vm.names[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `@Published` instead of `@Binding` in your view model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you describe a bit what you are trying to do?

If you want to pass the view model, you can us the same view model in both views:

```
struct V_NamesList: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM_App

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(vm.names.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, name) in
            TextField("New Player", text: $vm.names[i])
        }
    }
}
```

and you can pass the view model from the parent:

```
struct V_App: View {
    @StateObject var vm: VM_App = VM_App()

    var body: some View {
        V_NamesList(vm: vm)
    }
}
```

you will need to use @StateObject when you create and store the observable object view model.

Comment: I tried to move the list logic to it's own View with it's own ViewModel, @StateObject did the trick, thank you :)

Comment: How does this work? It’s one view model per view. It’s not testable or following the single responsibility principle if they are sharing the same view model.

Answer (score 0):

On SwiftUI View will track if your ObservableObject will change. So if you don't want to refresh the view once the data changes, just don't track for that `names` changes.

```swift
class VM_App: ObservableObject {
    var names: [String] = [
        "Tobias",
        "Jonathan",
        ""
    ]
}

struct V_App: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM_App = VM_App()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            V_NamesList(
                VM_NamesList(names: $vm.names)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Still, because you have `@Binding` it will set the names for `VM_App` but keeps it changes silently for your `V_App`.